# git reset --soft HEAD

Tags: git, github

I have a bunch of commits I don't want in my pull request, but I do not want to loose my work from previous commits. Will git reset --soft HEAD reset my commits to the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not.

Reset moves the HEAD to specified commit. Moving HEAD to HEAD does nothing.

You can reorder commits using interactive rebase (`git rebase -i`) and then you can push the specific commit (which includes all commits that precede, but not those that follow) rather than the complete branch to github.

Answer (score 0):

No. `git reset --soft HEAD` will do exactly absolutely NOTHING.

Just create a new branch at the last commit you want to include in the pull request and push that.

```
git checkout -b for-github <commit-id>
git push origin for-github
```

Assuming remote `origin` points to GitHub and you really want to call that branch `for-github`. Which is unlikely.

Your `master` branch will preserve all your other changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late, but you should consider squashing your commits. The following command will list your last 4 commits.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Then you will be presented with a list that looks like this

```
pick 01d1124 Adding license
pick 6340aaa Moving license into its own file
pick ebfd367 Jekyll has become self-aware.
pick 30e0ccb Changed the tagline in the binary, too.

# Rebase 60709da..30e0ccb onto 60709da
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Then replace `pick` for `squash` (or `fixup`) for those commits that you would like to delete from the history (without deleting the changes) and save. Your commits should be squashed into one.

Source:

http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History